# Patching MySQL Server from version 5.6.14 to 5.6.21

Tags: mysql, patch

I would like to "update" a MySQL server from version 5.6.14 to the latest GA release 5.6.21. I have already reviewed the MySQL reference at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html and Oracle's "How does Patching Work in MySQL?; How to Apply All the Latest Patches?; How to Find the Latest Patches (Doc ID 1589556.1)." But, these don't clearly explain the patching mechanism. The doc (id 1589556.1) instructs that "...to apply the latest patches to an existing installation, all that is required is to download and install the latest patch release." Well, will this not overwrite the existing server metadata and effectively make me loose the user, database, and privileges related info. in the existing server?

Please help with the exact patching steps or any link to a document with clearer instructions. Also, any gotchas, i.e., what do I need to watch out for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/installing.html

Hi,

I did an upgrade from 5.6.14 to 5.6.22 recently on our dev environment.  Please note this was on a Linux server

Backup database - I used MEB but MySQLDump or a cold backup is okay

Shutdown the database cleanly.
Upgrade the binaries (rpm -Uvh)
Start the database

I didn't need to run mysql_upgrade as the release has not changed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use yum update and its updated automatically into latest patchset.5.6.37.

So run "yum update" for centos or as per your linux distribution